# Что происходит, когда метод возвращает значение?

Tags: java

Допустим есть такой метод:

```
int val() {
  return 1 + 1;
}
```

Если его вызвать, не сохраняя в переменную таким образом:

```
val();
```

Что в этот момент происходит и почему компилятор не выдает ошибку?

Я думал, что при вызове метода, он просто заменяется значением, которое возвращает.

То есть, если написать такую строку кода:

```
System.out.println(val());
```

То `val();` заменяется значением, которое этот метод возвращает и код начинает выглядеть так:

```
System.out.println(2);
```

Но это не так. Ведь если написать просто число в коде, не присваивая его переменной, компилятор выдаст ошибку `error: not a statement`

Так что, метод не просто заменяется значением, которое он возвращает, а происходит что-то другое.

Объясните, пожалуйста

Comment: "компилятор выдаст ошибку error: not a statement" --- неправда!  http://tpcg.io/_YEE3BR   вполне всё работает

Comment: not a statement  возникает когда ты не так что-то написал, например в цикле пропустил необходимые знаки разделения

Comment: Я имею ввиду если написать вот так: tpcg.io/_3P9Q65

Comment: так конечно....а что ты этим хотел сделать? это в целом не по правилам ...вообще ни по каким......потому что код оперирует переменными и методами......а просто число что должно сделать? вот в целом, по задумке. просто висеть в воздухе? и тут дело не в том "что должен возвращать метод", а просто в том, что это невалидно по всем правилам языка

Comment: По этому я и хочу понять, что происходит, когда метод возвращает значение. Ведь если бы он просто его возвращал (то есть, заменялся на число), то код выдавал бы ту же ошибку, что и при обычном написании числа.

Comment: почему ту же ошибку-то? ``val();`` - корректная конструкция языка. statement. Вызывается функция, она что-то делает. То, что она возвращает число, дело десятое. Может и не возвращать, корректность не изменится. ``4`` - некорректная конструкция языка. Число само по себе стоять не может.

Comment: Этот момент теперь я понял, спасибо. Но куда девается это число, которое возвращает метод?

Comment: Про какое число речь?

Comment: "Ведь если бы он просто его возвращал (то есть, заменялся на число), то код выдавал бы ту же ошибку, что и при обычном написании числа" ---- почему? один метод принимает на вход какое-то значение..... другой метод возвращает какое-то значение...... всё совпадает

Comment: Под возвращаемое значение выделяется переменная соответствующего типа. В процессе вызова метод в неё записывает значение. Если вы это значение не используете, то оно так остаётся неиспользованным, лежащим в переменной.